# Numpy NDPointer: Don't know how to convert parameter 1

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I am trying to push a Numpy array into C++ code.

The C++ function is,

```
extern "C"
void propagate(float * __restrict__ H, const float * __restrict__ W,
               const float * __restrict__ U, const float * __restrict__ x,
               float a, int h_len, int samples);
```

My python code is,

```
from numpy import *
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libesn.so")

propagate = lib.propagate
propagate.restype = None
propagate.argtype = [ndpointer(ctypes.c_float, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),
                     ndpointer(ctypes.c_float, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),
                     ndpointer(ctypes.c_float, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),
                     ndpointer(ctypes.c_float, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),
                     ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]

H = W = U = X = zeros((10, 10))
a = 5.0
propagate(H, W, U, X, a, U.shape[0], X.shape[0])
```

I get error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./minimal.py", line 23, in <module>
    propagate(H, W, U, X, a, U.shape[0], X.shape[0])
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Stupid typos ... should be `propagate.argtypes`. This fixed the mysterious error leading to other errors that already have answers on StackOverflow.

```
propagate = lib.propagate
propagate.restype = None
propagate.argtypes = [ndpointer(ctypes.c_float, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),
                      ndpointer(ctypes.c_float, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),
                      ndpointer(ctypes.c_float, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),
                      ndpointer(ctypes.c_float, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),
                      ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
```